# Cascading implode on an array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, concatenation, implode

I'm looping through a set of data and pulling the following results:

```
$str[] = $id . '~' . $desc;
```

At the end of the loop I put these together:

```
$txt_str = implode('^',$str);

echo $txt_str;

1~one^2~two^3~three
```

Out of curiosity, could I get the same result by directly processing an array?

```
$arr[] = array('id'=$id, 'desc'=>$desc);
```

So something like:

```
$txt_str = makemeasammich('~', '^', $arr);

echo $txt_str;

1~one^2~two^3~three
```

Is there a native PHP function that has this capability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no such native PHP function.**
Use `implode()` and `array_map()` (with anonymous function):

```
implode('^', array_map(function($value) {
    return implode('~', $value);
}, $myArray));
```